# Copying / Reading files on iPhone

Tags: objective-c

I am copying a SQLite file to the "Documents" directory of my iPhone/Simulator.

First I deleted the app off my phone and from the simulator and the app folder disappeared in "Application Support / iPhone " folder.

I made changes to the structure, deleted old version and copied new version to my "Resources" folder. Restarted my app which then copied the file back to the "Application Support / iPhone " fine.

The problem was though the file seemed to be cached as it would not execute queries on the new tables I added?

I have now fixed this by following the above steps BUT also renaming the database, but was wondering if anyone could shed some light on this?

Thanks
James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to renamed the files as Cleaning the targets did not seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

When changing a ressource I always "clean all target" and delete my App from the iPhone (device or simulator) , so I'm sure it will make the change.
However if your sqlite database is located in you ressources directory and not in document directory , you w'ont be able to do action such INSERT or ALTER TABLE because ressource directory is READ ONLY ;-) .
I advise you to move your sqlite db in Document folder when the app launch ;-) .

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try a clean build. In Xcode: **Build** > **Clean All Targets**

Comment: This still did not work to get around this I named the database something else and then added that to the "Document" directory.